# What is the best way to organise your JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently now I'm organising my JavaScript functions as follows:

```
var websiteName = {
    options: {
        optionOne: "Boom!",
        optionTwo: "Hello World!"
    },
    init: function () {
        websiteName.homepageOnlyFunction();
        websiteName.anotherFunction();
    },
    homepageOnlyFunction: function() {
        // A function only used on the homepage
    },    
    anotherFunction: function() {
        /*
        A function that is used
        throughout the site.
        */
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    websiteName.init();
});
```

I would like some insight on what the best practice is for organising javascript.

Comment: [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) of course `:)`

Comment: Backbone is a silly library -.-

Comment: I prefer the "revealing module pattern" (Google it) because it lets you have both private and public functions and properties and the `websiteName.` prefix is only needed when referring to the public functions/properties from outside the library.

Comment: @Raynos It's a good choice for data-driven web-applications, is it not?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it's a good choice for "please hold my hand, I dont know how to architect code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally arrange my code as a set of modules (one module per file). Each module is an object that generally does one thing.

```
// x.js
...

module.exports = {
  ...
}
```

These modules are packaged together by a module packer like [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and then bootstrapped and initialized in some fashion.

I personally use a dependency injection library like [ncore](https://github.com/Raynos/ncore) to bootstrap my modules.

As for organization within a module, do whatever you want, have some module scoped functions, have some variables, have some objects, etc.

Comment: I think i will try this method.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how your website work, how scripts they interact in the DOM, how they interact with each other, how they interact with the server. there are a lot of patterns, especially [modular javascript](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw)

Comment: So let me expand on what I do. I'm a front end developer and never touch the server. I mainly do pretty things basically. But I like to reuse my functions on various projects.